# Is the vowel quadrilateral in IPA 3 by 2 or 3 by 3?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

I found some difference between the vowel quadrilateral from https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/IPA_chart_orig/pdfs/IPA_Kiel_2020_full.pdf

[image]

and the one from
https://pressbooks.pub/essentialsoflinguistics/chapter/2-8-vowels/

[image].

The first one is 3 by 2, and the second is 3 by 3. Is the second wrong? If not, why is it divided that way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would either of them be wrong? They both have three levels on the back–front axis, they just show them differently: the first uses the lines as indicators of where front/central/back is located; the second uses the cells (the space between the lines) as indicators of which space in the mouth they take up. The first sees the locations more as (ideal/deterministic) points on an axis, the second as larger areas. Both are perfectly logical.

Comment: Don't you mean that the first one is 3 by 4? Where are you seeing 2?

Comment: The lines are only helpers to avoid confusion by the sparsely filled rows and columns, they have no  inherent meaning. The symbols and their placement are the real content of the chart.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Look at it like a table; the top one is then three rows of two cells, while the bottom one is three rows of three cells.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, I see the visual effect. Whereas since most things are positioned at the nodes those are the real countables.

Comment: Can you qualify a little more what you mean by the second one being “wrong?” Are you asking which design we prefer? Obviously, vowel space trapezoids are really just concrete simplifications of something rather abstract, and the lines used to divide them are arbitrary. The 3 x 2 is more standard, but I like the other one as well - perhaps more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a question about what the standard IPA chart is. It is published in the handbook of the IPA, and [here is a PDF](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/IPA_chart_orig/pdfs/IPA_Kiel_2020_tooltips.pdf) from the IPA web page. The first one you link is from that chart, the second is someone else's re-interpretation. One clue is the labels. There are no "high" vowels in IPA, there are "close" vowels.

There is, of course, the question of who cares / what material difference there is – you could take away the reference lines and labels entirely and you would still have the same set of letters, except for the fact that the second chart doesn't bother with a bunch of the vowels.

Comment: Thanks. What differences are between https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/IPA_chart_orig/pdfs/IPA_Kiel_2020_full.pdf and https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/IPA_chart_orig/pdfs/IPA_Kiel_2020_tooltips.pdf

Comment: The hover-over description etc, on the "tool tips" version.

Answer (score 1):

The two charts are just two different ways of looking at it all. The first chart is very thorough and has a fuller range of vowels, and makes finer distinctions. The second chart is a bit less overwhelming, which is a nice start for people who are just learning about linguistics, so it fits the audience that the textbook is addressing.

Also, the vowels that appear in the second chart are those that tend to occur more frequently among the languages of the world, and make a good starting point for learning about vowels from a linguistic perspective.

The layout and position of the vowels in the second chart match up with the basic position of those same vowel sounds in the first chart. Ultimately, both charts represent the general "ballpark" area for each vowel relative to the others because the exact frequencies for any given vowel will vary a bit between languages, dialects, and even from person to person.